# If A , B are finitely generated R-algebras then $A\otimes_RB$ is a finitely generated $R$-algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, tensor-products

> $A$, $B$ are finitely generated $R$-algebras. $R$ is a commutative ring with $1$. Then how can I show that $A\otimes_RB$ is finitely generated $R$-algebra?

What I have tried: First I have to show that $A\otimes_RB$ is an $R$-algebra.For which I need to show there is a ring structure in  $A\otimes_RB$.The natural way of defining the multiplication is $(a\otimes b)(c\otimes d)=(ac\otimes bd)$.Well difineness comes from the universal property.Bt how can I show that $A\otimes_RB$ is finitely generated $R-algebra$.Help me.Thank you.

Comment: What do you think is still missing? The nice interplay between $R$-multiplication and module structure are verified straightforwardly. Let $a_1,\ldots, a_n$ and $b_1,\ldots b_m$ be generators of $A,B$. What finite set of generators for $A\otimes B$ can you think of then?

Comment: (This is a trap, since $a_i \otimes b_j$ won't work.)

Answer (score 4):

1. $R[X_1,\dotsc,X_n] \otimes_R R[Y_1,\dotsc,Y_m] = R[X_1,\dotsc,X_n,Y_1,\dotsc,Y_m]$.
2. An $R$-algebra is f.g. iff it admits a surjective homomorphism from some polynomial algebra in finitely many variables.

Comment: 3. The tensor product preserves surjections!

Comment: Both 1 and 2 I know, but then how can I apply these two to prove that?

Comment: Please explain it

Comment: This is a complete solution ...